# terminology for breakdown of liquid dielectric under the application of high voltage

Tags: decomposition

I saw a diagram a while ago of increasing voltage (x-axis) and what seemed to be the chemical decompositions of ethylene glycol as it occurred at various applied voltages. (I am not a chemist- sorry about poor terminology) I want to find that diagram or something like it again, and I am failing.

I hoped to see intermediary products, final products, and intermediary reactions that occur when glycol was used as a dielectric in pulse power applications (we call the product of that breakdown "streamers," which is super general).

Any suggestions on how to word my search for something like that?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd call this "dielectric breakdown"

Comment: thanks! someone (whom I work with) suggested "breakdown curve" too.

Comment: There are various forms of glow discharge, at low current levels where ohmic heating is not significant, such as plasma glow discharge (usually in a gas, but could also occur in liquid, or perhaps even in  solids) and contact glow discharge electrolysis, http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0963-0252/24/6/063001/meta